# How to show ModelState validation messages to the user on the initial GET

Tags: c#, validation, modelstate

Ok, So the people I'm working for want the form validation messages to show immediately on the initial load.  In my ViewModel I have all my requireds etc... which usually get hit on the POST, So how do I force the validation to take place on the GET so the user see's these validation messages when they first enter the form?

I've tried

```
ValidateModel(viewModel);
```

and

```
TryValidateModel(viewModel)
```

But these aren't working.  So is there an easy way?

So I have something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new RandomVieModel();

    ValidateModel(viewModel); //For example

    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(RandomViewModel viewModel)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("SomethingNew);
}
```

This is an example of my View Model:

```
public class RandomViewModel
{
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [MinLength(3)]
    public string SomeRandomText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RandomName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get those methods? Where and how did you tried those methods?

Comment: They are coming from System.Web.Mvc and I just tried them before I return the view in my controller

Comment: Silly question, but your viewModel class does have data annotation attributes, correct?

Comment: Yes it most certainly does.  I'll put an example above for you.  But it works on the POST.  I just want it to work on the GET.

Comment: TryValidateModel does what you are describing for me...

Comment: Hmm, strange because its not working at all here.  I've found a solution with jquery validation, so that will do. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

What will the validation messages have on an initial GET? Since nothing has "failed" yet (as those are validated on a POST), there will be no validation messages? (The user hasn't provided any input?)

If you are using your validation messages to guide the user on how they should be providing values ("Please enter an alpha numeric postal code"), you really should be not using validation messages for those. That's text that should always be there. If you are looking to avoid duplication of the same text  message, then use resource files.

If this is a temporary thing (and you know that already), then anything you do is going to be a hack.  Either add it to your HTML or change your controller so that it always checks for the validity of the model:

```
public ActionResult Index(RandomViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    if (Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Post) 
    {
       return RedirectToAction("SomethingNew");
    } 
    else 
    {
       return View(viewModel);
    }

}
```

The above is going to be your action method for GET and POST.

Comment: Thats the thing.  My clients want it to fail right away.  Thats what I want to happen.  (As stupid as it may be).
So basically I want what happens on the POST to happen in the GET so the error messages are shown.

Comment: Then just always show the text, in your HTML. As in write it out. You don't need to decorate your view model with it. Move it over to your HTML.

Comment: This isn't a permanent thing.  If it was, we'd do that.  But its only something for a few months.  I'm just looking for a "Hopeful" simple solution to force viewmodel validation to be triggered on the GET

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I found a temporary solution.  Luckily its not forever.

So I found that jquery validate is an ok option to use.  It will trigger the validation on the client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form-id').validate().form();
    });
</script>
```